# How to identify the time period in which an event happened and assign a specific value to this event in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two Excel tables. The first one is a list of 10-minute periods (over several weeks) and a specific value for each of this periods:

[image]

The entry "24.08.2016 14:10" stands for the period from 14:00 to 14:10 on August 24th, 2016

The second table consists of events and looks like this:

[image]

Now I want Excel to automatically fill up the "value" column in table 2 with the corresponding values from table 1 (which would be "5,1" for the marked "24.08.2016 14:03").
Any advice on how to do this?

Comment: You have not explained in what way "5,1" is supposed to be generated. NOTE: 5,1 is 5 and 1 IMO. It might be you meant "5.1" as in "five decimal 1".

Comment: Since your dates are in ascending order, you can use INDEX() and MATCH() with a match type of 1:  `INDEX($B$3392:$B$34xx,MATCH($A344,$A$3392:$A$34xx,1)+1)`.  MATCH() will find the position of the next lower date in the list, and adding 1 makes INDEX() return the value associated with the next higher date.

Comment: If any of the events are an exact match to a period boundary, this formula will give the wrong answer. If there are any exact matches, you'll need to check for those and use a formula with match type 0 instead.

Comment: @Hannu "five decimal 1" is exactly what I meant

Comment: @Hannu the question wasn't really focused on that in addition whenever you use a comma or a period to denote a decimal depends on your settings. It's just about matching the rows.

Comment: If your times are stored as values, and not as text, then you can easily do it with [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). If you need more help setting up your formula, then please include your data in an [editable format](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: On second thought, match type 1 returns the largest value *less than or equal to* the search value.  So the formula above will give you the right answer even for an exact match to a period boundary.  This is assuming that the upper boundary is included in the period and the lower boundary isn't. i.e. "24.08.2016 14:10" stands for the period from 14:0**1** to 14:10

Comment: @Bandersnatch Your formula is working as desired, thanks! If you post this as an answer I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your dates are in ascending order, you can use INDEX() and MATCH() with a match type of 1:

```
=INDEX($B$3392:$B$34xx,MATCH($A344,$A$3392:$A$34xx,1)+1)
```

MATCH() will find the position of the largest value less than or equal to the search value. This will be the next lower date in the list, and adding 1 makes INDEX() return the value associated with the next higher date.

So the formula above will give you the right answer even for an exact match to a period boundary.

Glad to be of help, @Simon.